# IAsyncEnumerable and throttling

Tags: c#, .net, iasyncenumerable

Is it possible to throttle the data when consuming `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`?
I have a stream of data coming in rapidly, and I'm only interested in the last element every N seconds.

Thanks.

Comment: The consumer drives the loop for fetching more elements from an `IAsyncEnumerable`. But the specific implementation might have already read ahead. But do you mean that you are fetching a new IAsyncEnumerable every N seconds, or waiting N seconds between enumerating individual elements?

Comment: This is a strange question. The enumerables don't have the concept of "coming fast". They are not observables. You can only talk about the delay they impose when you enumerate them. What does this `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` represent? Where is it coming from? Could you tell us more about it?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to make sense to have a different endpoint which returns the most recent event rather than a dealing with the stream.

If you have to deal with a queue/stream you could consume the events and assign each new incoming one to something like `latest` and read that at the desired interval.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to convert `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` to `IObservable<T>` and leverage power of `System.Reactive`

First, you need a converter. I couldn't find builtin so I've created my own

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

public class AsyncEnumerableToObservable<T> : IObservable<T>
{
    private readonly IAsyncEnumerable<T> _source;
    private readonly Subject<T> _subject = new();

    public AsyncEnumerableToObservable(IAsyncEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        _source = source;
        BeginConsume();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer) => _subject.Subscribe(observer);

    private async void BeginConsume()
    {
        try
        {
            await foreach (var item in _source)
            {
                _subject.OnNext(item);
            }

            _subject.OnCompleted();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _subject.OnError(e);
        }
    }
}

public static class AsyncEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<T> ToObservable<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new AsyncEnumerableToObservable<T>(source);
    }
}
```

With this converter you can use `myEnumerable.ToObservable()` and use `Sample` method for throttling from `System.Reactive`

```cs
static class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAsyncEnumerable<int> seq = CreateSeq();
        seq.ToObservable().Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }

    private static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> CreateSeq()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            i++;
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a built-in `ToObservable` operator in the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) package. Beware of conversions between enumerable and observable sequences. Enumerable sequences are meant to be enumerated. They produce the next item only when the consumer requests it (`MoveNextAsync`). On the other hand observable sequences produce items autonomously. They don't negotiate with the consumers. So converting from the one model to the other might have unexpected consequences.